# Change MapView orientation

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, direction

I want to change the OSMdroid MapView orientation to face the direction which the user is going (calculated with `Location.bearingTo` between the previous and current user location on each `onLocationChanged`, and converted into normal degrees instead of the -180/180° East of True North degrees).

This direction is correct, I'm rotating an arrow image towards this direction and it points towards the right direction without fail.
However, when I want to orientate the MapView to these userDirection using the `setMapOrientation` method (documented [here](http://osmdroid.azurewebsites.net/osmdroid-android-4.3-javadoc/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.html#setMapOrientation(float))), this isn't working as I want it to be. When I orientate the map towards the user's direction, the arrow image should always be pointing north, right? Because this is want I want to achieve: to make it seem like the arrow is always pointing forward (like a GPS tracker: your location on GPS is always represented by an icon going forward, my arrow is pointing to all kinds of directions because the map orientation is wrong).

I'm guessing the `osmdroid.MapView orientation` is expecting another sort of degree value, but I've tried converting back to East of True North degrees, didn't work. Or my logic is completely wrong and it *is* working correctly.

How do set the orientation for the `MapView` so that it is always facing the user's current direction, so that the arrow is always pointing forward (and not going backwards, right or left, ... )?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are referring to as is "True North" orientation of Map using the compass True North. For this you need the device Compass or Sensor Listener to get the direction, after getting the heading you need to set it for the MapView. Here is the Snippet which is very helpful.

```
private void compassHeadingUp() {

        if(enableCompassHeadUp){
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        } else {
            mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mySensorEventListener);
            mDirection = 0;
        }
}

public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
        synchronized (this) {
            float mHeading = values[0];             
            if(Math.abs(mDirection-mHeading) > Constance.ROTATION_SENSITIVITY){
                mMapView.setMapOrientation(-mHeading);
                mDirection = mHeading;
            }
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            mCompassImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            matrix.postRotate((float) -mHeading, mCompassImageView.getDrawable().getBounds().width()/2, mCompassImageView.getDrawable().getBounds().height()/2);
//Set your Arrow image view to the matrix
mCompassImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm implementing it right now but I have one question: what's the use of the `enableCompassHeadUp` variable? What does it check?

Comment: Its just a boolean to enable or disable the sensor, so that you can have an option to On/Off

Comment: The variable `Constance.ROTATION_SENSITIVITY`, from where is this retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by inverting degrees like this:

```
float bearing = location.getBearing();

float t = (360 - bearing);
if (t < 0) {
   t += 360;
}
if (t > 360) {
   t -= 360;
}

//help smooth everything out
t = (int) t;
t = t / 5;
t = (int) t;
t = t * 5;

mapOSM.setMapOrientation(t);
```